# In admin edit-menu screen, newly added menu items always go to the bottom of the list

Tags: menus, wp-admin, user-interface

In admin edit-menu screen, newly added menu items always go to the bottom of the list. the only way to move it to the top is to drag/drop the item. I am a developer building a custom mega menu and the client has potentially hundreds of menu items to add and 3 to 4 tiers deep. To maintain a menu of this size seems unwieldy, not to mention take all day and then some. Ive been searching for a solution, but have not found anything. I would think there would be a plugin that gives the ability to insert a menu item at a given location without needing to drag/drop the item allllll the way 20 screen-lengths up. 
Any ideas?

In the past, ive zoomed out on the screen and changed the height (via css) of the list items to very short so I could drag/drop farther/faster. But this still is not a solution to a huge mega menu.

I could do away with the wordpress way of doing menus and build the mega menu using ACF. But id like to do it the wordpress way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a good solution to this:
Here are two power tips for managing long wordpress menus in wp admin:

**Method One:**
As you click and drag the menu item up (with mouse button down), hit "pageup" (or "pagedown") button(s) on your keyboard.

**Method Two:**
Click the top right arrow of the metabox to expand the menu item details. Look for Move options and click "up one" or "down one". From there, the menu item is focused and you can use your keyboard arrows to blast past the page screen. You can even nest under other items using right and left arrows. Give it a try.